# How are constexpr functions implemented by compilers?

Tags: c++, constexpr

I was wondering about this recently. How is evaluation of constexpr function calls at compile time implemented by compilers such as gcc?

The most convenient way seems to use the function's compiled machine code or more likely some compiled intermediate code and execute it, but this has some problems. In the 2020 standard dynamic allocation was allowed in constexpr functions. What if a constexpr function has some incorrectly written memory management code and say, tries to double-free a pointer? It'd be better if the compiler didn't crash in such a case. What if it smashes the stack and overwrites data elsewhere in the compiler process? Similarly, it'd be better if the compiler didn't crash. Does the compiler execute it in a sandbox environment? How does it detect such memory errors? What does it do if such memory errors happen? Does the compiler instead emulate the function some other way? Thank you.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but is much too broad. Even if you ask about only one implementation, I think it's too broad.

Comment: Compilers have indeed to check out of bound accesses and other UBs.

Comment: Your "most convenient way" also won't work for cross-compilers.

Comment: I think you're question might be more appropriate if you ask about a specific example instead of any general function. Also if you ask closer to one question. As of know you're asking 7, which means that answering becomes very difficult as it has to cover all 7 to be an appropriate answer.

Comment: While this is a broad question, I think a broad answer would be acceptable. Compilers interpreting code have access to much more information than compiled code (such as array lengths, object lifetimes, etc). I expect symbolic execution plays an important role

Comment: @alterigel A good proxy for "broad" would be "length". I suspect that any answer that reasonably addresses this question would take at least several pages of text. If you feel that you can answer it briefly, then go for it, I have no issues with that.

Answer (score 4):

Basically they evaluate constexpr by using a special constexpr interpreter.

Here you can read/watch about clangs implementation

- https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ConstantInterpreter.html
- https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2019-July/062799.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LgrgYD4aibg

It's too much for a simple answer...